# How to I keep my entire box from turning white on hover

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm hoping someone can take a minute and look at my responsive web page and let me know what CSS rule I need to write to keep the boxes in the collapsed state of the menu from turning completely white on hover. I can't see my white txt links underneath. I tried this rule and it didn't work:

```
.nav-collapse .nav > li > a, .nav-collapse .dropdown-menu a:hover {
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

If you resize your browser until the top nav collapses, you will see what I mean when you open the collapsed menu and hover.

[Page I'm creating is here:](http://skeeterz71.com/auto/nav.html)

Using tw bootstrap - Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: `.navbar .nav > li > a:hover { text-decoration:none; }`

Comment: @mint that's wrong ...

Comment: @setek: isn't it going to override the `text-decoration:underline;` rule?

Comment: @mint OP's issue is of the entire colour of the link turning white on hover. Not the underline of the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override the style for the appropriate media query. To only target the menu when it's collapsed, you can do:

```
@media (max-width: 979px) {
    .nav-collapse .nav > li > a:hover, .nav-collapse .nav > li > a:focus, .nav-collapse .dropdown-menu a:hover, .nav-collapse .dropdown-menu a:focus {
        background-color: transparent;
    {
}
```

Or if you want to apply it universally to all resolutions:

```
.nav-collapse .nav > li > a:hover, .nav-collapse .nav > li > a:focus, .nav-collapse .dropdown-menu a:hover, .nav-collapse .dropdown-menu a:focus {
    background-color: transparent;
{
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the line:

```
background-color: transparent;
```

To the rule:

```
.navbar .nav > li > a:hover { ... }
```

.. which is on line 43 of your "main .css" (why is there a space after main and before the file ext?)

Comment: (why is there a space after main and before the file ext?) I have no clue. I used dreamweaver's linking utility. That's how it did it. If I take the space out the styles disappear. I'll have to investigate this. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Exactly. Your filename is `main .css` not `main.css` ... it's not the cause of any problem, it's just .. not great to put spaces in filenames on the web.

Comment: If you take the space out of the filename, you have to update the links in the HTML to the new filename.